# Repository pattern design

Tags: laravel, architecture, repository, repository-pattern

I'm refactoring my code which consists of controllers, to a repository design.

I find the hard part, thinking about the responsibility of a specific domain/functionality.

I have a `ExchangeController` which has a `trade` method. In this method it is possible to change a `Shift` with another Shift.

So I was thinking about having a `ExchangeRepository` with the trade method, but then I have to retrieve a `Shift`.

Isn't it bad practice to retrieve a `Shift` directly from the model (`Shift::find($id)`), but to encapsulate it by calling `$shiftRepository->get($shiftId)`?

Im starting to learn it but sometimes it's really hard to figger some things out.
Is it good practice to try and encapsulate most things to its own, instead of just going and reach for the model?

I hope it's a bit clear, lol..

Comment: You would encapsulate this to remove logic from the controller. If the repository is dependency injected as an interface I could easily create my own "ExchangeRepository" that did something different without changing the controller (or any other code, other than possibly the IoC binding to the interface)

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of repository is to hide database manipulations from other code. You are not required to have one repository per every model or per every table. That will lead to a very nasty consequence: inability of executing complex queries against database. You will have to split them into small simple ones each against its own table.

> Isn't it bad practice to retrieve a Shift directly from the model
>   (Shift::find($id)), but to encapsulate it by calling
>   $shiftRepository->get($shiftId)?

I don't actually like to call something "bad practice". It all depends.

Calling model collection methods directly in controller may look simplier and it's quicker to write, but as complexity of your application grows, you will start to have troubles. For example, try to add caching to your application with `Model::queryMethod()`-like calls spilled through your code.

So, as a summary I'd recommend you to split your queries into repositories. Choose repositories wisely. Don't pay attention to your table names, but to the domain logic of your application.

Comment: Thanks. So if the idea is to write the database logic in a repository, what is the common way of writing the business logic?

Comment: @guidsen In a medium-sized projects (as my current one) I create entites I call Services. I put bussiness logic into them. But strictly speaking this is not Service Oriented Architecture as it can seem from the name. Just a way to decouple bussiness logic. You will want to create a separate namespace for services because as they grow, they will represent a whole layer in your software.